# How to you configure the command prompt in Linux to show current directory?

Tags: linux, zsh

How to you configure the command prompt in Linux to show current directory? I want to be able to put settings for this in the .zshrc file.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can place this to your `.zshrc` file

`export PS1="%d %% "`

`%d` denotes the CWD

For more details go [here](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zsh/HOWTO#Prompts) for example

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Comment: My favorite is linux-like (username@host:PATH$) export PS1="%n@%m:%d$ "

Answer (score 11):

I use `"%20<...<%~%<<"` in my `$PS1`, so that if a prefix is found in the current working directory, it is replaced by `~`: it works with `$HOME` (replaced by `~`), home directories of users (replaced by `~user`), and directories defined by `hash -d` (e.g., if one has `hash -d foo=$HOME/path/to/dir`, then this directory is replaced by `~foo`). The `%20<...<` and `%<<` allows zsh to truncate the directory on the left side if it is too long, in order to avoid a too long prompt.

Answer (score 11):

Like Jiri Kremser said, you can change the prompt using `PS1` variable. For example, if you want to change prompt to something like this (show the current path relative to HOME dir):

[image]

use the following setting in `.zshrc`,

```
export PS1="[%~]$ "
```

Then `source .zshrc` to make the change take effect.

The official zsh doc on prompt variables can be found [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).

Comment: The brackets cluttered is up a little but thanks great answer

Answer (score 2):

Add `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` to your PROMPT variable. Or just `$PWD` if you don't want it to show ~ for your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `agnoster` theme for `ZSH` then you could customize path length inside `.zshrc` file as shown below

1. To show the `full path`

   ```
   prompt_dir() {
      prompt_segment blue black '%~'
   }
   ```

Example: `/mnt/c/personal/repo/myprojects/alphagame $`

2. To show only the `current directory` instead of `full path`.

   ```
   prompt_dir() {
      prompt_segment blue black '%1~'
   }
   ```

Example: `alphagame $`

3. Similarly to show only `last 2 directories` instead of `full path`

   ```
   prompt_dir() {
      prompt_segment blue black '%2~'
   }
   ```

Example: `myprojects/alphagame $`

Comment: Best one is the `'%2~'` :)