# Show current branch on prompt on zsh shell

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to display the git branch on prompt on Big Sur.
So I have created a script file to run for each new session `.zshrc`

```
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ [\1]/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[01;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

The above doesn't work it actually displays the string not its outpupt.

```
\u@\h \W\[\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $
```

How can I show current branch in prompt on zsh shell?

Comment: Your post has only statements. This is a Q&A - "Question & Answer" forum. Is there a question you want to ask? Please read [ask].

Comment: @PetrosKalafatidis : `\u` has no special meaning in a PS1 for zsh. Therefore it is printed literally. The same applies for your other elements in the prompt string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to you configure the command prompt in Linux to show current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090295/how-to-you-configure-the-command-prompt-in-linux-to-show-current-directory)

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want to display something like this `[username@computername directory](branch)`

The code below should do it for Zsh which is a little more involved than accomplishing the same task in `bash`. There are multiple solutions to this, and you can find more information [here](https://medium.com/pareture/simplest-zsh-prompt-configs-for-git-branch-name-3d01602a6f33) if you are interested.

Add the following to your .zshrc or .zsh_profile

```
# Load version control information
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }

# Format the vcs_info_msg_0_ variable
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'

# Set up the prompt (with git branch name)
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

PROMPT='[%n@%m %1~]%F{green}(${vcs_info_msg_0_})%F{white}$ '
```

It would be beneficial to read up on the differences between `bash` and `zsh` as you cannot use solutions found online interchangeably.

Comment: This works perfectly. I slightly adjusted to change the color and punctuation. `PROMPT='%n@%m %1~%F{cyan} (${vcs_info_msg_0_})%F{white} % '`

Comment: It was not obvious to me that the above must be added to your `.zshrc` file in order to be permanent. Hopefully this helps others. The article linked to in this answer is helpful as well.

Comment: The problem though is that the branch's name appears only if you `source` the file. If you close the shell and start a new one, everything in the prompt message gets evaluated except for the VCS info. Apparently you'd have to load them manually.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a script that would do the same on MacOS but didn't find a good answer so I just built it looking up zsh a little bit.

The other answers are right that you the answer is that you're using bash symbols instead of zsh symbols however below is a solution I made.

Add the following to your ~/.zshrc or ~/zprofile

```
###
# ADD GIT INFO TO PROMPT
###
parse_git_branch() {
  local branch=""
  branch=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')
  local git_status=$(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null)
  local color=green
  if echo "$git_status" | grep -q "^ M"; then
    color=yellow
    branch="${branch}*"
  fi
  if echo "$git_status" | grep -qE "^ A|^\?\?"; then
    color=yellow
    branch="${branch}+"
  fi
  if echo "$git_status" | grep -q "^ D"; then
    color=yellow
    branch="${branch}-"
  fi

  if [[ -n "$branch" ]]; then
    branch=[%F{${color}}${branch}%F{reset}]
  fi
  echo "$branch"
}
update_prompt() {
    PS1="%n %1~$(parse_git_branch) %#"
}
precmd_functions+=(update_prompt)
update_prompt
```

This will label your branch and give a little mark if there's changes.
If you don't need the mark, only keep the first line in `parse_git_branch`

If you need the computer name change `%n` to `%n@%m`.

Remember to re-open the terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` after you make your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Bash PS1 is not ZSH PS1, they differ. The `\u \h` etc. sequences are substituted by bash, they do not work in ZSH. Research both shells and how they differ.